# When i hover over the button it's getting huge

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I have just started to learn html, css and javascript. My question is when hovering over the button, its size changes and i simply dont know why. I have centralized the button settings and using it like this;

App.css file

```
:root {
    --yellow: #F5C32C;
    --orange: #FCA61F;
    --black: #242D49;
    --gray: #788097;
    --blueCard: #DDF8FE;
    --purple: rgb(238 210 255);
    --purpleNew: #f857a6 ;
    --boxShadow: 0px 19px 60px rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
    --orangeCard: rgba(252, 166, 31, 0.45);
    --smboxShadow: -79px 51px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.App {
    padding: 0.5rem 3.5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: var(--black);
}

.button {
    border-radius: 34px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 11px 26px 11px 26px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#ff5858,#f857a6);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
.button:hover{
    background: white;
    flex: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--purpleNew);
    border: 1px solid var(--purpleNew);
}
```

Intro.jsx file

```
import React from "react"
import "./Intro.css"
import Github from "../../img/github.png"
import LinkedIn from "../../img/linkedin.png"
import Instagram from "../../img/instagram.png"
import Vector1 from '../../img/Vector1.png'
import Vector2 from '../../img/Vector2.png'
import boy from '../../img/boy.png'
import thumbup from '../../img/thumbup.png'
import Crown from '../../img/crown.png'
import glassesemoji from '../../img/glassesimoji.png'
import FloatingDiv from "../FloatingDiv/FloatingDiv";
const Intro = () => {
    return (
        <div className="Intro">
            <div className="i-left">
                <div className="i-name">
                    <span>Hy! I Am</span>
                    <span>Yigit Gunes</span>
                    <span>text will be here</span>
                </div>
                <button className="button i-button">
                    Hire me
                </button>
                <div className="i-icons">
                    <img src={Github} alt="" />
                    <img src={LinkedIn} alt="" />
                    <img src={Instagram} alt="" />
                </div>

            </div>
```

Intro.css file

```
.Intro {
    display: flex;
    height: 77vh;
    margin-top: 6rem;
}

.i-left {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2rem;
}

.i-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.i-name > :nth-child(1) {
    color: var(--black);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.i-name > :nth-child(2) {
    color: var(--purpleNew);
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.i-name > :nth-child(3) {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: var(--gray);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.i-button {
    width: 6rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 34px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 11px 26px 11px 26px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff5858, #f857a6);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.i-right {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.i-right > * {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.i-right > :nth-child(1) {
    transform: scale(0.69);
    left: -10%;
    top: -5%;
}

.i-right > :nth-child(2) {
    top: -3.6rem;
    transform: scale(0.67);
    left: -3rem;
}

.i-right > :nth-child(3) {
    transform: scale(1.4);
    left: 14%;
}

.i-right > :nth-child(4) {
    transform: scale(0.6);
    top: -19%;
    left: -24%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0;
}

.i-icons {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    gap: 0rem;
}

.i-icons > * {
    transform: scale(0.5);
}

.i-icons > * {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.blur {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22rem;
    height: 14rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #edd0ff;
    z-index: -9;
    top: -18%;
    left: 56%;
    filter: blur(72px);
}
```

I want it to stay at the same size during the hover. Can you guys please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this piece of code from App.css file

```
.button:hover{
    background: white;
    flex: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--purpleNew);
    border: 1px solid var(--purpleNew);
}
```